# Can someone teach me about html helpers

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

how can I write an html helper in cakephp 3 , 
Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in C:\wamp\www\newsite\src\View\Helper\Helper.php on line 2 
Here is the code in a file called helper.php

```
//<?php
namespace App\View\Helper;

use Cake\View\Helper;

class Helper extends Helper
{

}
```

help me whatg do i have to do

Comment: *"Can someone teach me about html helpers."* - Stack isn't a teacher.

Comment: There's stacks of documentation just a Google search away..

Answer (score 1):

Before your question was edited, your first line in listed this:

`//<?php`

You can probably fix that fatal error by removing the `//`, the first thing in the page MUST be exactly:

```
<?php
namespace App\View\Helper;
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should change :**

```
//<?php
  namespace App\View\Helper;
  use Cake\View\Helper;
  class Helper extends Helper{

  }
```

**To :**

```
<?php
  namespace App\View\Helper;
  use Cake\View\Helper;
  class OtherHelperClassName extends Helper{

  }
```

> **Note :** You are declaring and extending same `Helper` class. This is not Ok.

Here is an example to create `CakePHP 3` Custom `Helper`

**Create file** in `src/View/Helper/YourCustomHelper.php`

**In file `YourCustomHelper.php`**

```
namespace App\View\Helper;
use Cake\View\Helper;

class YourCustomHelper extends Helper{
  public function makeEdit($title, $url){
    #Your custom magic is here :)
  }
}
```

Here is the CakePHP official documentation for creating [CakePHP3 Helper](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers)